# c++ program to find solution of guessing game

Tags: c++, random

I am reading book called "jumping into c++" in which it wants me to build a program that find the solution of a guessing game that picks a number between 1 and 100 randomly and let user guess what the number is and tells them whether their guess is high,low or just right.
Basically it wants me to predict the next random number but i am unable to figure out a way to do so since i am a newbie.

This is the code of guessing game:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int x,y;
int rand_range(int low, int high)
{
  return rand() % (high - low) + low;
}

int main()
{
  int seed = time(NULL);
  srand(seed);
  int y = rand_range(1, 100);
  cout << "Program has picked a no. between 1 to 100... You just make a 
           guess....\n";
  cin >> x;
  while(1)
    {
      if(x == y)
       {
          cout << "just right\n";return 0;
       }
      else if(x < y)
       { 
         cout << "low\n";return 0;
       }
      else
       {
         cout << "high\n";return 0;
       }
   }
}
```

This program let the user guess a number between 1 to 100 and then check whether the guess is low,high or just right but I need a program which solve the above guess problem and guess the random no. exactly.
Means I need a way to predict the next pseudo random number.

Comment: sample input and output please

Comment: You need to explain what doesn't work exactly (what you want and what you get instead).

Answer (score 2):

Your code has some fundamental errors. First of all you need to take input in a loop. Secondly, you are returning in all the conditions. That's why your code is trying to match the target only once. And you have to take input in a loop because you want to try to guess the number. For that you have to take input each time. I have edited your code slightly. Please check the below code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int x,y;
int rand_range(int low, int high)
{
  return rand() % (high - low) + low;
}

int main()
{
  int seed = time(NULL);
  srand(seed);
  int y = rand_range(1, 100);
  cout << "Program has picked a no. between 1 to 100... You just make a guess....\n";

  while(1)
    {
    cin >> x; // Now taking input in the loop
      if(x == y)
       {
          cout << "just right\n";return 0;
       }
      else if(x < y)
       { 
         cout << "low\n"; //omitted the return line
       }
      else
       {
         cout << "high\n"; // omitted the return line
       }
   }
}
```

To guess the next pseudo random number you have to assume a deterministic algorithm. It is too broad for a question and way too much difficult for a newbie. Please see this post - [Is it possible to predict the next number in a number generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371972/is-it-possible-to-predict-the-next-number-in-a-number-generator)

Answer (score -1):

I've edited your code. You were putting code in an infinite loop, but you exited out of the loop for every possible case, so there wasn't a valid point to it. Instead, you should have a loop that ends once the user guesses the correct input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int x,y;
int rand_range(int low, int high)
{
    return rand() % (high - low) + low;
}

int main()
{
    int seed = time(NULL);
    srand(seed);
    int y = rand_range(1, 100);
    cout << "Program has picked a no. between 1 to 100... "
         << "You just make a guess....\n";
    cin >> x;
    while(x != y) {
        if(x < y)
           cout << "low\n";

        else
           cout << "high\n";

        cin >> x;
    }

    cout << "just right\n";
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: How this suppose to work? You are taking input only once. If the number does not match with y, your program will continuously print `high` or `low` for an infinite time.

Comment: Oops sorry I missed that. Fixed the while loop so it keeps taking in arguments to from the command line.