# Counting probabilities based on a set of possible outcomes and previous outcomes

Tags: random, probability, reverse-engineering

How do I calculate the probability of the RNG picking the next result from the set based on previous results? Are there any methods to analyse this type of RNG activity?

For example, we know the 50 possible options that the generator can choose and the last 10,000 results. I would like to calculate the probabilities for the next selection.
Thanks for any help and suggestion.

Comment: You can think of it as a machine learning problem, but I doubt that you will get a good success rate. If you know the RNG, then it might be possible to recover the inner state. For example, knowing 624 successive states of the Mersenne Twister is enough to recover the state. On the other hand, it would be harder if all you know is how it chose between 50 options 10,000 times in a row since in that case you have lost information. Also, if the RNG is cryptographically secure then you are out of luck.

Comment: Thank you for your response. For sure It will make it easier for me to choose a way to solving the problem. Greetings!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371972/is-it-possible-to-predict-the-next-number-in-a-number-generator